# Double clicking on back-button causes site to go back two pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, back-button

If I have a page structure with three of more pages where p1 links to p2 which links to p3, and I double click on the back button on p3. That will cause the page to go back to p2 and then instantly back to p1.

Is there any way to prevent such behaviour?

[JSFiddle example code](http://jsfiddle.net/SfqSa/3/)

Comment: Is this a trick question? Did you try *single*-clicking the back button on p.3?

Comment: Haha :) The problem is that if someone runs the app on a slow phone, they might think they missed the button and click it again. That would cause it to go back two pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom data-clicks attribute and keep the click count in that. When you navigate back a page, reset the counter.

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/SfqSa/39/

JS

```
$('#p3').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    $('#goBackOne').click(function() {
        // if 0 (zero) clicks go back 1
        if($('#goBackOne').attr('data-clicks') == 0) {
            $('#goBackOne').attr('data-clicks', 1);
            history.back(-1);
        }
    });
});

$('#p2').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
   // reset to 0 (zero)
   $('#goBackOne').attr('data-clicks', 0);
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1">
    <a href="#p2" type="button">Go to page 2</a>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="p2">
    <a href="#p3" type="button">Go to page 3</a>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="p3">
    <a href="#" type="button" id="goBackOne" data-clicks="0">Back</a>
</div>
```